# How to return DISTINCT values in a JSON_ARRAYAGG when using JSON_OBJECT

Tags: mysql, distinct, mysql-5.7, json-arrayagg

How to use DISTINCT with JSON_ARRAYAGG?

Let's consider the below query as an example.

```
SELECT 
    staff.company,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'uuid', UuidFromBin(staff.uuid),
            'username', staff.username,
            'name', staff.name,
            'surname', staff.surname
        )
    )
FROM events_staff
JOIN staff ON staff.id = staff_id
LEFT JOIN skills s ON s.id = events_staff.skill_id
GROUP BY staff.company
```

Now, How can I use DISTINCT with JSON_ARRAYAGG in this query so that JSON objects will be distinct? It will be better if we can apply DISTINCT based on any key like **uuid**.

After googling for half an hour, I found the below options but was not able to apply these in the above query.

> A JSON_ARRAYAGG DISTINCT returns a JSON array composed of all the
> different (unique) values for string-expr in the selected rows:
> **JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT col1)**. The NULL string-expr is not included in
> the JSON array. **JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT BY(col2) col1)** returns a JSON
> array containing only those col1 field values in records where the
> col2 values are distinct (unique). Note however that the distinct col2
> values may include a single NULL as a distinct value.

Comment: Please post sample data. By the way, what's the purpose of doing a left join with `skills` table? I don't see it being used anywhere in the query.

Comment: I have removed other selects so that question will be dedicated to the actual query.

Comment: That's understandable but you still haven't post data sample. In any case, I think there's nothing wrong with `JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT col1)` **IF** the `col1` is actually a column that stores valid JSON value. Your `col1` is basically a generated JSON value from a few different columns and I'm guessing since you're grouping by `company`, your results returned duplicate `staff`. I suggest you apply the `DISTINCT` on the columns before you do `JSON_TABLE()` then only you do `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` - possibly without even including `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have came to a workaround to solve this issue, First addressing the issue that using `JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT())` Will simply not work.

So the workaround is `CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT("key": value)), ']');` this will result in something like this `[ {"key": <value1>},{"key":<value2>}, ...]`. this will return distinct result.

*Note*: You might need to cast this as JSON in the end this can be done like this =>  `CAST(CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT("key": value)), ']') AS JSON);`

Comment: This seemed to work for me. Not sure why MySQL doesn't support DISTINCT with JSON_ARRAYAGG. Seems like other DBs do.

Comment: Maybe in later versions this would be fixed until then this solves the problem

Comment: Let's hope MySQL implements this soon. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91993 MariaDB has DISTINCT in JSON_ARRAYAGG for at least 2 years already https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_arrayagg/

Comment: It's January 2023 and this is still necessary. Anyway, thank you very much for this.